# WPF bubbling mouseenter and mouseleave events for animation purposes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, event-bubbling

In my application there is a control, which contains amount of cards, on each of them is a ToggleButton placed. I will apply some effects on MouseEnter the card, and i will to apply another effect on the button, when mouse if over it, but not declining the effect of the card. But MouseEnter and MouseLeave events are not bubble events, they catchs in control and disapears. What is the simpliest way to resolve this collision?

This is a simplified XAML code.

XAML

```
<Grid>  <Image Source="{Binding Path=PosterPath, Converter={StaticResource imageConverter}}" Opacity="1.0">
        <Image.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect ... />
        </Image.Effect>

        <Image.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Image.MouseEnter">
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource ShowMenuAnimation}"/>
            </EventTrigger>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Image.MouseLeave">
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource HideMenuAnimation}"/>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Image.Triggers>

    </Image>

    <ToggleButton x:Name="bPlay" ...  
                  IsChecked="{Binding Path=(common:CommonViewSettings.AlwaysFalse), Mode=TwoWay}" 
                  Style="{DynamicResource MetroCircleToggleButtonStyle}" 
                  Foreground="{DynamicResource LinkedTextBrush}" Visibility="Hidden"
                  BorderBrush="{DynamicResource LinkedTextBrush}">
        <Rectangle Fill="{Binding Path=Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ToggleButton}}}">
            <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill" Visual="{DynamicResource appbar_control_play}"/>
            </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
        </Rectangle>
        <ToggleButton.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.MouseEnter">
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource ShowBorderBrush}"/>
            </EventTrigger>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.MouseLeave">
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource HideBorderBrush}"/>
            </EventTrigger>
        </ToggleButton.Triggers>
    </ToggleButton>
```

Comment: Please post the complete code to reproduce this problem. (A [mcve])

Comment: I have corrected the code, and returned missed tags. Or you need the whole code?